# How to access the variables in console in Selenium script for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am actually testing an application and want to see if data is correctly coming or not and for that I am sending the context through which we can access the data to console. Now, how to access the context which I passed to console from my script?

Comment: Provide some code snippets as what are you trying to do.

Comment: in console I have a variable context = 4;

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit. Its not clear as what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am actually doing this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/82z4qcmu/5/) But it gives me error saying the variable is not defined. So, I want the variable to be accessed after the event is listened. @eduPeeth .

Comment: @SuryavamsiTenneti please also paste that code inside the question to provide a context for other members without having to look into comments.